# Python SqlAlchemy querying Session with Unicode value in 'filter_by' returns null

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode, sqlalchemy

I have a (MS SQL) db table in which one of the columns, `keyphrase`, is of type `nvarchar`. I have set up my SqlAlchemy model of this table to have type `String(convert_unicode=True)` for this column (I have tried making it of type Unicode too but this hasn't helped either).

I am calling an API which returns keyword values. I want to check if a returned `keyphrase` value already exists in my db. I do this by calling:

```
Session.query(Keyword).filter_by(keyphrase=api_keyword_value).first()
```

This works for all English characters. However, when I query the session for a value containing European characters, such as  ä, é, ô, ü, the query call always returns null. I can check the db manually and see that there is definitely a value in the db, but for some reason it is not being returned by my SqlAlchemy query.

I am assuming that, as it only occurs when searching for entries with European characters, this is a character encoding issue. However no exceptions are thrown so I'm not sure exactly where this is going wrong or how to fix it! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like my strings were sometimes being detected as unicode, sometimes not? Don't really know how that bit works.... I made a little function to check I was always inserting/searching for unicode values and it works just fine.

```
def make_me_unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return s.decode('utf-8')
    elif isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s
    else:
        return None
```